# Visual studio code C external files

Tags: c, eclipse, visual-studio-code, extern

Whenever I try to use extern variable in another .c file of the same folder or if I want to use external function I get an error: ld returned 1 exit status

While if I am trying to use eclipse for the same example it works with no errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can **use** a (extern) variable, you have to **declare** it first and then **define** it.

**Example**

Declare the var in a header file, e.g. *foo.h*:

```
extern int my_extern_var; //declaration (extern)
```

Define it in a source file, e.g. *foo.c*:

```
#include "foo.h"   //include the declaration
int my_extern_var; //definition
```

Then use it in any other source file(s):
(even if *foo* is a library and get linked to the program below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h" //include the declaration

int main() 
{
    my_extern_var = 42; //usage of 'global' var
    printf("%d\n", my_extern_var);

    return 0;
}
```

**Reference:**

- [Storage-class specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) (cppreference.com)

Comment: I am still getting error : (undefined reference to 'my_extern_var' )
Plus when I use extern in eclipse I don't need a header file and it works just by two source files mentioning extern variable in main will refer to the other.c file

Comment: Either you declare it in a header file and include it where it is gonna be used, or you declare it in every source file. The point is, it has to be declared somewhere as extern and defined somewhere else, the var can also be declared and defined at the same time, like `extern int my_extern_var = 42;`. Check your sources, where the declaration is and where it is defined. Maybe, you show us some code?